# JS adding hover class between two divs when the class is unknown.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have a map view and a list view of some hotels which have the following attributes:

```
/*List Result*/
<div class="hotel-result hotel-23456">
  ...Content...
</div>

/*Map Result*/
<div class="map-hotel-result hotel-23456">
  ...Content...
</div>
```

The class shared between the two elements `hotel-23456` changes on every hotel result because it's being created by concatenating a string (`hotel-`) with the hotel's database ID.

What I would like to happen, using jQuery, is that when the user hovers over the list result the map result receives an attached class of `hover` which will highlight it on the map.

The issue I am having is that there can be up to 50 hotels showing at anyone time and I am unsure how to select and bind the two when the `hotel-[id]` class is constantly changing? Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `el1.onmouseover = function(){ el2.className = this.className; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've blocked out how I might approach this. Code is not tested but should give you the general idea.

```
<div data-hotel-id="23456" class="hotel-result hotel-23456">
  ...Content...
</div>

/*Map Result*/
<div class="map-hotel-result hotel-23456">
  ...Content...
</div>


var $hotelListResults = $('.hotel-result');
var $hotelMapResults = $('.hotel-map-result');

$hotelListResults.hover(function(){
  var hId = $(this).data('hotel-id');
  $hotelMapResults.not('.hotel-'+hId).removeClass('hover');
  $('.hotel-'+hId).addClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Great idea! I hadn't even thought about using data attributes. This works perfect thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If your classes are as you have pointed out - you could do something like this:

```
$('.hotel-result').on('mouseenter',function(){
    var classname = $(this).attr('class');//result should be 'hotel-result hotel-2465';
    var mapclass  = '.map-'+classname.replace(/ /g,'.');//this is basically replacing 'space' globally with '.', class identifier in jQuery

    $(this).addClass('Your_hover_class');
    $(mapclass).addClass('your_hover_class');
});
```

This should work. Needless to say, similarly you have to bind a mouseleave to remove the classes.

Was about to suggest! data-id solution by @david is the right and non-hacky way of doing it.